# Select multiple rows if specific columns have value

Tags: sql, firebird, fastreport

I have a table like this (simplified):

Table name: products

```
productId, property, value
----------------------------
1, color, red
1, shape, square
1, price, 1.00
...
2, color, green
2, shape, triangle
2, price, 0.50
...
10, color, red
10, shape, circle
10, price, 3.00
...
```

I simplified it, but I hope it makes sense. I have multiple rows for one particular dataset, product in this case. Each row describes a different attribute of the product.

I now want to select all products with a paticular attribute, lets say all products where the `color` is `red`. But not only the row where color is red, rather every row for every product where the `color` is `red`.

I'm sorry, this is described terribly, but I hope you know what I mean. Given the table structure above, if I want to select all red products, I'd like to end up with something like this:

```
productId, color, shape, price
-------------------------------
1, red, square, 1.00
10, red, circle, 3.00
```

Does this make sense? Maybe someone can help.

By the way: I can't change the given table structure. It comes from an external application.

Comment: Is the list of properties fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses `exists`:

```
select p.*
from products p
where exists (select 1
              from products p2
              where p2.productId = p.productId and
                    p2.property = 'color' and p2.value = 'red
             );
```

If you want this all one one row, then you can use conditional aggregation to summarize:

```
select p.productid,
       max(case when p.property = 'color' then p.value end) as color,
       max(case when p.property = 'shape' then p.value end) as shape,
       max(case when p.property = 'price' then p.value end) as price
from products p
group by productId
having max(case when p.property = 'color' then p.value end) = 'red';
```

Comment: That's it. Worked like a charm (the second one). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the pivot command. It’s the best way i’ve Found to translate rows into columns, provided the columns are static.  If they aren’t it’s possible to do it via dynamic sql but a bit more complicated.  I use that method to build views for product attributes, which sounds pretty similar to what your doing here.

Comment: Firebird doesn't have a pivot command.

Comment: Sorry I missed the firebird tag. Unless there are any objects I won't remove the question incase any future users find it useful. I will say though that before using pivot, @GordonLinoff has posted thye solution I used to use. +1 for that.

Comment: @MatthewBaker Indeed this second suggestion worked like a charm.